# R: Summary specific categorical values

Tags: r, summary

I am trying to perform the following R function:

```
summary(UNdata_2000_2014,UNdata_2000_2014$Year==2000)
```

I simply want to summarise only the values when `year==2000`. But I get a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (length(ll) > maxsum) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In maxsum:length(ll) :
  numerical expression has 114 elements: only the first used
3: In if (length(ll) > maxsum) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In maxsum:length(ll) :
  numerical expression has 114 elements: only the first used
```

Any help for interpreting this ?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.

Comment: Try `summary(subset(UNdata_2000_2014, Year == 2000))`

Comment: That's it docendo ! Thanks a lot for your help !!